# Encontrar a primeira tag após um nome de class e muda-la com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de identificar o primeiro `class='active'` no meu html e após adicionar um valor na class do elemento `<ul>` seguinte, porém só do primeiro elemento `<ul>`

**Meu HTML**

```
    <aside class="navigation">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav teste-nav">
                    <li class="active">     //AQui primeiro active
                        <a href="#categoria1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cat. 01<span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="stroke-arrow"></i> </span>
                        </a>
//mudar essa ul
                        <ul id="categoria1" class="nav nav-second collapse in">
                            <li><a href="#"> Países</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="#"> Estados</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Cidades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Bairros</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Logradouros</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#categoria2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            Cat 02<span class="sub-nav-icon"> <i class="stroke-arrow"></i> </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul id="categoria2" class="nav nav-second collapse">
                            <li><a href="#"> Países</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#> Estados</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Cidades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Bairros</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Logradouros</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
```

Gostaria de com jquery identificar o primeiro `li` com class `active` e ao identificar trocar a class do `a href` para `nav nav-second collapse in`

estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$(".active").after(function () {
     $("ul").toggleClass("in");
});
```

mas ele coloca o 'in' em todos os ul seguintes.

tentei também:

```
$("ul:first").toggleClass("in");
```

ou

```
$("ul").fir.toggleClass("in");
```

Mas não adiciona o in.

Comment: `$('.active ul:first').toggleClass("in");` Isso que precisa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$(".active").after(function () {
    $(this).find("ul:first").toggleClass("in");
});
```

Pode fazer direto também:

```
$('.active ul:first').toggleClass('in');
```

Comment: funcionou somente a 2ª opção...valeu